# Error: Getter not found: 'SyncfusionLicense'

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, flutter-web

I am trying to run flutter web with syncfusion charts but i get this errors from syncfusion library while registering the license -->
Error: Getter not found: 'SyncfusionLicense'

I am on flutter beta channel and syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^18.1.36

Please suggest solutions if anyone has faced it before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

syncfusion_flutter_charts is commercial package, to use this package you have to perches licence.

there are two type of [licence](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/blob/master/LICENSE) available.

> 1)community
>
> To be qualified for the Syncfusion Community License Program you must
>   have a gross revenue of less than one (1) million U.S. dollars
>   ($1,000,000.00 USD) per year and have less than five (5) developers in
>   your organization, and agree to be bound by Syncfusion’s terms and
>   conditions.
>
> 2)commercial
>
> Customers who do not qualify for the community license can contact
>   sales@syncfusion.com for commercial licensing options.

To purchase licence you can contact in following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/account/login

Answer (score 0):

Yes i had purchased the license. 
Error is solved, I found that usually when integrating flutter for web flutter core package is to be commented out and that is what contains the definition of registerlicense of syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

We would like to ensure that if you have registered the license key in your application like in the below screenshot. If you have registered the license, you don’t need to comment anything and after register your key, it will not throw any license related pop up messages. And we would like to let you know that, if you have installed our chart widget package, then you no need to install our core(syncfusion_flutter_core) package separately, since chart package is dependents on the core.

[image: license]